# How to view full body message in browse queue in ActiveMQ Artemis web console

Tags: activemq-artemis

I send a message to queue in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.20, and I navigate to web console to view the message, but only a limited characters I can see. Can I configure the web console to visualize the full message body in the queue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to [ARTEMIS-3141](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3141), [ARTEMIS-3128](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3128), & [ARTEMIS-3175](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3175) the data returned for any `list` or `browse` management method which return message data, including those exposed via the web console, have their return data truncated by default. This is done to avoid adverse conditions with large volumes of message data which could potentially negatively impact broker stability.

The `management-message-attribute-size-limit` `address-setting` controls this behavior. It is `256` by default. It can be disabled using `-1`. I recommend you set it to a value sufficiently high for your use-case.

To be clear, this applies to every release *after* 2.18.0.

Comment: 0

Does the API enable the features of a linked list or similar? Fon an example, can I go to the next 200 or the previous 200 and so on?

Or is the purpose something else that I miss?

Comment: @DemasSinner, you should ask a _new_ question about this.