# I see only partial message and not full message

Tags: activemq-artemis

In my queue hosted by ActiveMQ Artemis 2.19.0 I see only partial message and not full message. Where can I increate the setting to see full message?

I am viewing the messages by logging into the web console, going to "Queues" tab, selecting the message count, and clicking on "show" in the "Action." It is displaying only partial message. It is saying "+ 162 more" and not displaying the full message, e.g.:

```xml
<ral:RallyUserData xmlns:ral="xmlns.citizensfla.com/Rally">
   <ral:DisplayName>Ashok2</ral:DisplayName>
   <ral:Division>Test2</ral:Division>
   <ral:EmailAddress>test2.ing@gmail.com</ral:EmailAddress>
   <ral:EmployeeID>123421</ral:EmployeeID>
   <r, + 162 more
```

I am expecting to see the full message in the queue instead of partial message.

Comment: I am using apache-artemis-2.19.0.I am viewing the messages by logging into the console and going to Queues tab.select on the message count and click on show in the Action. It is displaying only partial message.It is saying +162 more and not displaying the full message.

<ral:RallyUserData xmlns:ral="http://xmlns.citizensfla.com/Rally">
<ral:DisplayName>Ashok2</ral:DisplayName>
<ral:Division>Test2</ral:Division>
<ral:EmailAddress>test2.ing@gmail.com</ral:EmailAddress>
<ral:EmployeeID>123421</ral:EmployeeID>
<r, + 162 more

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view full body message in browse queue in ActiveMQ Artemis web console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126960/apache-activemq-artemis-2-20-how-to-view-full-body-message-in-browse-queue-in-w)